# Spotify Web-API and JSONP

Tags: spotify

I'm working with the new Spotify web-API and try take calls with IE9. Is it possible to get a JSONP-callback from the WEB-API?

Thank you!

Comment: We currently do not support that unfortunately.

Comment: CORS headers would b good enough I guess?